# how to find exact source location on google map in android

Tags: android

In my app, there is a search box, user can enter any specific location, and i have to show that exact location on map. I searched a lot but not getting the exact answer. Please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Google cannot give you location values for some vague locations. May be you can fetch all the locations from "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json" API. use the predictions and set to autocomplete textview.Once they select any location you can reverse geocode the location and get latitude and longitude values from that and set it to map.